# Add and commiting a file into SVN using SVN-Kit jar

Tags: java, svn

Actually i want to commit source into svn. I need to add and commit new files into svn repository and am using the below code. Code works properly but not able to commit into SVN

```
    String urls = "http://192.168.0.19/svn/cadgraf/Branch/Jobs";
    final String url = urls+File.separator+l_users.getSelectedValue().toString()+File.separator+"Active";
    System.out.println("svn url------>"+url);
    final String destPath = "/home/dev702/Desktop/Jobs-test/Tempfiles";
    SVNRepository repository = null;
    setupLibrary();
    try {
        //initiate the reporitory from the url
        repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url));
        //create authentication data
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager =
                SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
        repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        //output some data to verify connection
        System.out.println("Repository Root: " + repository.getRepositoryRoot(true));
        System.out.println("Repository UUID: " + repository.getRepositoryUUID(true));
        //need to identify latest revision
        long latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
        System.out.println("Repository Latest Revision: " + latestRevision);

        //create client manager and set authentication
        SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
        ourClientManager.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        //use SVNUpdateClient to do the export
        SVNCommitClient commitClient = ourClientManager.getCommitClient();
        commitClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
    commitClient.doCommit(new File[]{new File(destPath)}, false, "Commit message", null, null, false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
        SVNCommitClient client = new SVNCommitClient(authManager, null); 
         SVNCommitInfo info; 
         info = client.doCommit( new File[]{new File(destPath)}, false, "Commit message", null, null, false, false, SVNDepth.INFINITY);
    } catch (SVNException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```

code works fine but its not commiting files into SVN.

Comment: Is there anyway to import into SVN also its ok for me.. please suggest

Comment: Suggest if there is any other way to commit or import into svn using java

Comment: Java experts answer plz....

Comment: i itself found the solution for import

Comment: why not update your question with the solution  you got? This way someone (like me) who is exactly looking for same issue can get assistance.